# How to write a Ruby switch statement (case...when) with regex and backreferences?

Tags: ruby, regex, switch-statement

I know that I can write a Ruby case statement to check a match against a regular expressions.
However, I'd like to use the match data in my return statement. Something like this semi-pseudocode:

```
foo = "10/10/2011"

case foo
    when /^([0-9][0-9])/
        print "the month is #{match[1]}"
    else
        print "something else"
end
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

---

Just a note: I understand that I wouldn't ever use a switch statement for a simple case as above, but that is only one example. In reality, what I am trying to achieve is the matching of many potential regular expressions for a date that can be written in various ways, and then parsing it with Ruby's Date class accordingly.

Comment: Ruby's Date.parse understands many date formats. Have you tried it?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer this question, you might want to look at the Chronic gem...

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The references to the latest regex matching groups are always stored in [pseudo variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pseudo_Variables) `$1` to `$9`:

```
case foo
when /^([0-9][0-9])/
    print "the month is #{$1}"
else
    print "something else"
end
```

You can also use the `$LAST_MATCH_INFO` pseudo variable to get at the whole `MatchData` object. This can be useful when using named captures:

```
case foo
when /^(?<number>[0-9][0-9])/
    print "the month is #{$LAST_MATCH_INFO['number']}"
else
    print "something else"
end
```

Comment: @Yossi Do you have a source for your comment regarding thread safety? I just did an experiment in ruby 1.8.7 that seems to indicate that it is thread-safe! (Thread matching a regex every one second - checking in irb if local matches are getting clobbered)

Comment: -1 $variables to do with regular expressions are not global even though it has a dollar sign in front of it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of it. I'll have to change a lot of old code :-/

Comment: You can also do `$1`, `$2` ... `$9` or `Regexp.last_match(1)` as recommended by rubocop

Comment: If `$LAST_MATCH_INFO` isn't available you'll either need to use `$~`, or `require 'English'` which sets up the alias

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative approach that gets you the same result but doesn't use a switch. If you put your regular expressions in an array, you could do something like this:

```
res = [ /pat1/, /pat2/, ... ]
m   = nil
res.find { |re| m = foo.match(re) }
# Do what you will with `m` now.
```

Declaring `m` outside the block allows it to still be available after [`find`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is done with the block and [`find`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) will stop as soon as the block returns a true value so you get the same shortcutting behavior that a switch gives you. This gives you the full [`MatchData`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/MatchData.html) if you need it (perhaps you want to use named capture groups in your regexes) and nicely separates your regexes from your search logic (which may or may not yield clearer code), you could even load your regexes from a config file or choose which set of them you wanted at run time.

Comment: I was also thinking about thread safety using the `case` approach. Maybe you want to use mu's approach in a threaded scenario, rather than a global variable with the case approach(?)